# Connecting program to dictionary

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm writing [this](https://github.com/Sela12/Scattegories/blob/master/Scattegories(WIP).cpp) program for the game "Scattegories" and I would like to connect some sort of dictionary (to check if the words exist) to the program.
If I were to do that how would I do it?

```
// A program to keep track of points and time and to give a random letter for the game scattergories
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::getline;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

void ltr()    //gives a random letter
{
    srand(time(NULL));    //gives a differant pattern every time
    char letter;
    letter = rand() % 26 + 65;         //assigns a random letter in ascii code to a char (resulting in a random letter)
    cout << "The letter is " << letter << "\n";
}

void timer()
{
    cout << "You got 1.5 minutes to finish\n";    //Changing the duration of the timer is done by changing the value of 'i' in the "for" loop
    for (int i = 90; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << i << "\n";
        sleep_for(1s);
    }
    cout << "DING DONG!!! DING DONG!!! Time's up!!!\n";
}

void table()
{
    int plr, ctr;
    string lst[5][20];           //first dimantion: how many players. second dimantion: how many catagories, third dimantion(if added) will be the round
    cout << "How many players?";
    cin >> plr;
    cout << "How many catagories?";
    cin >> ctr;       //parameters for later
    cin.ignore();                  //To avoid the "getline" reading the last input
    for (int x = 0; x<plr; x++)       //the player changes only after the previus player finishes
    {
        cout << "Player number " << x+1<<":";
        timer();       //gives time to write the words. Optimaly it would run in the background while each player writes the words.
        for (int i = 0; i<ctr; i++)        //changing catagory
        {
            getline(cin, lst[x][i]);
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << "Next player\n";
    }
    for (int x = 0; x<plr; x++)                   //this part (the whole "for" loop) is for confirming evreything is writen down
    {
        cout << "Player number " << x + 1 << ": ";
        for (int i = 0; i<ctr; i++)
        {
            cout << lst[x][i] << "    ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    sleep_for(5s);
}

int points()        //points gained per round
{
    int a, b, c, sum;
    cout << "How many sections only you got?\n";          //worth 15 points
    cin >> a;
    cout << "How many words only you got?\n";       //worth 10 points
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many words you and another person got?\n";    //worth 5 points
    cin >> c;
    sum = a * 15 + b * 10 + c * 5;
    return sum;           //Note: It doesn't matter how many sections there are.
}

int act()    //running the program
{
    int Points;
    ltr();
    table();
    Points = points();
    cout << "You have earned " << Points << " this round\n\n";
    return Points;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int Points;
    cout << "Starting in five seconds\n";
    sleep_for(5s);
    Points = act();
    for (;;)          //inf loop
    {
        int ph;
        cout << "Press 1 to continue or anything else to stop\n";
        cin >> ph;
        if (ph == 1)
        {
            Points += act();    //keeping score of the rounds
        }
        else
        {
            auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "You have earned a total of " << Points << " great job!";
    sleep_for(5s);       //time to read the last text
    return 0;
}

/* 
   To do list:
   -Convert to arduino
   -Make timer work in background of of table
   -Check if words in the table (for differant players) are the same and give points accordingly
   -Check if words are actual words (connect an online dictonary?)
   -Make interface? (if possible and I have time to learn how)
   -Think of what to do with Hardwear
   -Comment rest of the code
   -Make a point count for each player
   -change "srand" placement
*/
```

Please keep in mind that I'm relatively new to programing (almost half a year), so please try to explain it as simple as you can, thanks.

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Off topic: Only call `srand` once per program unless you have a really really good reason. It restarts the random number generator so you'll probably keep getting the same number over and over if called within the same second.

Comment: On topic: [read up on `std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be an interesting exercise to implement your own dictionary.

Use a large array of characters to store the words, sorted alphabetically, each null-terminated. In addition, keep an array of indexes, each pointing to the start of a word.

Then implement a dichotomic search for lookup. It will be fairly efficient because you will find a word after at most `Log(N)` string comparisons, each taking between `1` and `L` character comparisons, where `L` is the word length.

---

A solution based on hashing can be more efficient, but is a little harder to code.

Comment: Would using a two dimensional array, with the first dimension sorted by the alphabet and the second dimension the words? I would check the first letter of the word entered and look for the word only in that dimension.

Comment: @Sela12: no sure what you mean but no, a 2D array is irrelevant. Checking the first letter vs pure dichotomic search is a waste of time.